# Using Sweave, how can I reliably get .PNG figures instead of .EPS or .PDF figures?

Tags: graphics, sweave, literate-programming

I have tried to set the options in the preamble:

`\SweaveOpts{keep.source=TRUE, eps=FALSE, pdf=FALSE, png=TRUE}`

but this does not reliably produce only `.png` (or indeed any!) figures. I say 'reliably' as I have been successful previously in getting the `.png` figures, but having made some modifications to my document (alas, unscientifically) Sweave no longer produces any figures.

Answer (score 5):

There is no option for automatic PNG output in the official Sweave distribution.  The only options are PDF or EPS-- you are not seeing output because you have turned both of those off.

You can use whatever output device you want by forgoing the use of `fig=TRUE` and writing code that looks like:

```
\begin{figure}

\caption{Some silly plot.}
\label{fig:sillyPlot}

<<fig1>>=
png( 'fig1.png' )

# Plotting stuff.

dev.off() # <- very very important
@
\includegraphics{fig1}

\end{figure}
```

Instead of:

```
\begin{figure}

\caption{Some silly plot.}
\label{fig:sillyPlot}

<<fig1,fig=TRUE>>=

# Plotting stuff.

@

\end{figure}
```

The `fig=TRUE` option really just saves some typing by freeing you from opening the device, closing it and then inserting the `\includegraphics{}` command for LaTeX.  If you really want `fig=TRUE` to support PNG output you will have to roll your own modified Sweave driver or use [this one](http://sites.google.com/site/thibautjombart/r-packages) created by Thibaut Jombart.